# R replace a word in a column based on a numeric value in another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset in which I am wanting to change the word in the `variable` column based on the values in column `b`.

So, the intent is that when the value of `b` is not equal to `0` change the corresponding values of `Variable` from `a` to `b`.

How can I do this?

Sample Data:

```
structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), b = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 23.5, 24.5, 28.6, 12, 17), Variable = c("a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Desired output:

```
structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), b = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 23.5, 24.5, 28.6, 12, 17), Variable = c("a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)

df = df %>% 
  mutate(Variable = if_else(b != 0, "b", Variable)) # Not using the right syntax stuck...

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `Variable = if_else(b != 0, "b", Variable)`.
Caused by error in `if_else()`:
! `false` must be length 10 (length of `condition`) or one, not 29232.
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error here.  `df %>% mutate(Variable = if_else(b != 0, "b", Variable)) %>% pull(Variable)#
 [1] "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b"`

Comment: @akrun yes you are right there was a typo in the code. Thank you for your time sir. On my computer I was writing ` df = dff %>%   mutate(Variable = if_else(b != 0, "b", Variable))` so `dff` was throwing that error as my data was actually stored in `df`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>%
  mutate(Variable = ifelse(b > 0, "b", Variable))
```